# Get the class element id using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I load the page and type this into the console:

```
 $("div .maps_popup");
```

I get the following shown to me:

```
 <div class="maps_popup" id="2">
```

So from there in my code I have the following:

```
 $("div .maps_popup").on('click', function () {
             var store_id = $(this).id;
                 alert(store_id);
  });
```

And when I click on the icon in the map - I do not get the alert in the browser for the id. So something isn't right. Can someone adjust my code and let me know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
I've tried all the examples on this thread and none seem to work. The page is at: http://test.theslickfeed.com/index.php

Click on any of the icons on the map and again open developer tools and then go to the console and do:

$("div .maps_popup")
You will see the div tag there.

None of the examples work so far :(

**UPDATED AGAIN**
This is my present code and it still isn't doing what it should be which is snagging the id of the maps_popup class and passing it to the url for a panel refresh:

```
 $("div.maps_popup").click(function(){
                    var store_id = this.id;
        var pathname =  "ajax=1&store_id="+store_id+"&action=get_nearby_stores&distance="+distance+"&lat="+lat+"&lng="+lng+"&products="+$('#edit-products').val();

        $("#pocp_content").load("file1.php?" + pathname);
 });
```

Comment: Is the issue that the alert doesn't show up, or that the ID isn't in the alert?

Comment: The alert doesn't show up - I am not sure yet if the id isn't in the alert or not

Comment: `$.fn` doesn't have an id property.

Answer (score 1):

```
alert(this.id)
```

is all you need. jQuery is not needed to retrieve that info.

jQuery has already bound `this` to the div which is what you are seeing in the console.

---

**EDIT**

You selector is jacked up `div.maps_popup` not `div .maps_popup`. The second selector would match (looking for a child element with class maps_popup):

```
<div>
    <div class="maps_popup"></div>
</div>
```

However, this previous statement `this.id` is required as well.

**LAST EDIT BEFORE I DELETE THIS**

`distance` is not defined in:

```
var pathname =  "ajax=1&store_id="+store_id+"&action=get_nearby_stores&distance="+distance+"&lat="+lat+"&lng="+lng+"&products="+$('#edit-products').val();
```

You have way too many errors. You ***need*** to focus on writing cleaner code. Look at the damn console output.

Comment: Joe didn't work. I've tried all kinds of variations and still nothing alerts me with the id

Comment: Your selector was also wrong. So there were actually two issues.

Comment: This is my selector now: $("div.maps_popup").click(function(){ and yet still not getting the id even using the this.getAttribute('id)';

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Nuu2c/ There's a functioning example of this two fixes for your question.

Comment: I get that it works in jsfiddle, but when I copy the same code and put it into my js and reload the page and click it doesn't work. Here's the page: http://test.theslickfeed.com/index.php

Answer (score 0):

`id` isn't jquery function. It's javascript's but there is an alternative for jquery. There's how to fix it:

```
 $("div .maps_popup").on('click', function () {
         var store_id = $(this).attr('id');
             alert(store_id);
 });
```

Comment: aksu - doesn't seem to work. I've tried that example and still no alert box

Answer (score 0):

Listen for document load, and change .id to .attr('id'):

```
$(function () {
    $("div .maps_popup").on('click', function () {
        var store_id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(store_id);
    });
});
```

Comment: bagonyi - doesn't seem to work. You can see the example here. http://test.theslickfeed.com/index.php Click on an icon the map. That's where it should at least be showing me an alert with an id.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways. I'd suggest one of the last two.

```
 $("div.maps_popup").on('click', function () {
             $(this).attr('id');
  });

 $("div.maps_popup").on('click', function () {
             this.id;
  });

 $("div.maps_popup").on('click', function () {
             this.getAttribute('id');
  });
```

Comment: I was hoping that the this.getAttribute('id'); would work but it doesn't. var store_id = this.getAttribute('id'); alert(store_id); is what I have and still nothing alerts me.

Comment: This is your problem. Your selector should be div.maps_popup or just .maps_popup : http://jsfiddle.net/5hD5j/

Comment: flat out - does not work. It may work in jsfiddle but it doesn't work in my code. I have copied and pasted it from jsfiddle and still nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

The short way to do it is you'll need to use

```
$(this).attr('id')
```

to retrieve what the value is of the ID field, the better way to do it which has higher performance is by retrieving it from the dom object like this

```
this.id
```

Comment: +1 for mentioned that `this.id` is the best way to do this.  Single property reference rather than two function calls.

Comment: Nemesis02, I get that it works in jsfiddle, and I see it, but when I copy the same code from jsfiddle and add it to my js file and reload the page, it doesn't work. You can see the page at: http://test.theslickfeed.com/index.php

Comment: It looks like the reason that's not working is cause you're applying the click event before you render the popup.  Correct me if i'm wrong, but i'm looking at the super-store-finder-mobile.js line 316.  That event never gets attached to your bubble so it never fires.  Try re-arranging the order these are called and rendered.